# how do i store or save excel file in the custom or specific folder?

Tags: php, export, export-to-excel

how do i store or save excel file in the custom or specific folder? i have the working code and code is working but only problem is that i can't store excel files in the specific folder?

**Main Page**

```
<form action="itemexcel.php" method="post" 
onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>")
.append( $("#ReportTable").eq(0).clone() ).html() )'>

<table id="ReportTable" width="781" border="2"> Or <div id id="ReportTable">
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay"></td>
<td><input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel"></td>
</tr></table></div>

<input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay">
<input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel">
```

**itemexcel Page**

```
<?php
$path = "/excelreports"; 
$file=$path."productexcel.xls";
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file."');
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```

Comment: You can't control (or even suggest) where a browser should store a download file... that's the prerogative of the browser and user

Comment: And "/excelreports" concatenated with "productexcel.xls" gives "/excelreportsproductexcel.xls"... did you want another "/" in there?

Comment: @MarkBaker i want to do like this 

<?php
$path = “/home/alamatweb/www/sms”; 
$fullPath = $path.“dataku.xls”;

header(“Content-type: application/octet-stream”);
header(“Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=”.$fullPath);
header(“Pragma: no-cache”);
header(“Expires: 0”);
?> but with this code

Comment: You can't.... you can't tell me where a file that __I__ download to __my__ PC will be stored... and I don't have a "/home/alamatweb/www/sms" directory on my PC either

Comment: @MarkBaker i'm creating php inventory system so i need to store in my pc only ?

Comment: You still can't do it if you're using a web browser, browsers don't allow you this level of control, they offer the user (you in this case) the choice rather than allowing any server script or http response headings to control it... try saving to a shared drive or similar rather than browser download